# Printing barcode on M-T532AP

Tags: c#

my question is the following.
I have `M-T532AP`i think its Epson's, its connected on serial port and now i need to print some barcode , and i am not sure how , i managed to print some text and its working.I know how to generate the barcode but the printing is where i get stuck. I searched google and every forum but i cannot find any solution.
Here is some code example that i have which is printing some text.

```
 serialPort1.Write("64sad61651\n");

 serialPort1.Write("6461asf651\n");

 serialPort1.Write("64616asd51\n");

 serialPort1.Write("64616asd51\n");
```

Comment: `ZXing.Net` is a good `Nuget` package for barcodes

Comment: Thanks , but my question is how to print the barcode on thermal printer connected to serial port

Comment: Oh, how are you currently printing? `Print Jobs` and `Print Tickets` are probably the way to go, that way you can create xps documents and insert the barcode in that way.

Comment: I am opening the serial port and using serialport.writeline("Some text");

Comment: You can only pass text doing that, how do you expect to be able to send a, usually bitmap, barcode? you could convert the image to `Byte[]` but that will likely confuse the printer.

Comment: Well i was thinking of doing it that way with the bitmap , i will try it , do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: For example would it be this way Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(picture path)

Comment: To load a bitmap? yes

Comment: And how would i print it ? can you help me with some example code ? i am really new to this xD Thanks for the comments

Comment: Ok, I'll start on an answer, might take me some time.

Comment: Thank you a lottt